# Ping response time suddenly rose up to average 1500ms or more

Tags: linux, networking, centos

At normal situation the ping (8.8.8.8) response time is 50ms. But out of sudden it just peaked to 1500ms average or more and quite frequent recently. My server is CentOS 6.6 with eth0 (192.168.1.1) connected to 3Com switch and eth1 (public IP) directly connected to SDSL modem. Service running, WWW, DNS and mail server. Firewall iptables/fail2ban.

So when ping response time going up, I notice by unplugging eth1 make it back to normal not immediately but gradually. So any advise what should I do?

Comment: You most probably have a loop in your network.
Check into that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this really an answer, but it seems that after powered off then on the SDSL modem making it back to normal. So I guess the modem is the culprit. Anyway I'm still using it.

Thanks.